# Saving file works in Jupyter and Pycharm but not VSCode

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble running my Python script from VSCode on macOS. It's not saving a file, even though that I believe that my code is correct because it's working in Jupyter and PyCharm.

Any idea, what could be wrong, please? I've tried to add access in settings for VSCode.

```py
import json

spam_db = {
    123 : { "phone": 1234567890, "email": "john@doe.com", "web": "my@domain.com"},
    122 : { "phone": 1234567890, "email": "john@doe.com", "web": "my@domain.com"},
    124 : { "phone": 1234567890, "email": "john@doe.com", "web": "my@domain.com"},
    125 : { "phone": 1234567890, "email": "john@doe.com", "web": "my@domain.com"},
    126 : { "phone": 1234567890, "email": "john@doe.com", "web": "my@domain.com"},
    128 : { "phone": 1234567890, "email": "john@doe.com", "web": "my@domain.com"},
    }

j = json.dumps(spam_db)
with open('spam_db.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
    f.close( )

print(spam_db)
```

Comment: It probably does write the file somewhere if you're not getting an error message, just not in the place you expect. Try adding `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` to your program and see what directory the script is actually using as its working directory. Your file may be written there.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. If the code run in VSCODE, it creates a .json file, two directories up from the directory where the source .py file is located. If it's run in the PyCharm, the .json file is created at the same directory. That's strange.

Comment: Run `import os  print(os.getcwd())` in this python script will show your current working directory, then `spam_db.json` should be generated there.

Comment: @DeLucasso in PyCharm, you configure the working directory for a script in the so-called 'Run configuration' and by default, that is set to the same folder where the script itself lives. In VSCode, depending on how you started your project and added the script, it can be some other folder - but you can change and configure it (or you can modify your script to change directory to where it lives itself, so that it always works that way)